# How to programatically add current file / buffer to agenda file list

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

I really like that when I click on a tag of a headline, org mode will show all headlines that have that tag in the "Headlines with TAGS match" list.

However, in order for this to work, I need to add the current file / buffer to the agenda using `C-[`

I also always want to see the agenda for the current buffer only, and so I use

```
C-c a < a
```

to do that.

In both of my above use cases, I need to press extra keys to add or show the current buffer/files in the agenda.

I realized that maybe I could programmatically do this, ie:

1. Add current buffer/file to agenda file list,
2. Make sure other buffers are removed from the agenda file list.

So I started searching the net and stackexchange for a solution.

I haven't found a solution, but I think I can use something like:

```
 '(org-agenda-files (buffer)))
```

And have been trying to code this but I have not been able to progress further.

I did ask a similar question here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63941124/emacs-org-mode-agenda-always-use-current-buffer?rq=1
and the solution was great (thanks NickD)
but now I would like to add the current file so that it works with both the agenda and the tag list, ie to not bind it to a particular key, but just have it happen without needing to press any keys (if that is possible).

Any help is appreciated on this.

Thanks as usual to everyone and happy holidays and best wishes for 2023!

Comment: See [Custom Agenda Views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html) in the manual.

Comment: Thanks NickD I will try that